View disappearing below scrollview
Here's my view:

The blue view is the scrollview. The red view is the content view.
The label below the scrollview gets hidden when I present a safari view controller.
I have TabNavBar and NavigationController to this VC.
When I present the safari controller I hide the TabNavBar and show again when it is being dismissed.
However, when I return to this page, the label below the scrollview disappears.
I think it has to do with the hiding of the tabbar.
I have tried using hugging and compression. Even fixed height for my label, it still disappears.
It is a intermittent problem and only happen a couple of times. So to reproduce this I have to uninstall the app, then I can see the issue a couple of times. Then somehow it works correctly after a while.
Update:
I have found the issue. It only happens because I had ModalPresentationStyle = OverCurrentContext when I present the safari controller
if I change it to CurrentContext then the problem is gone.
Anyone knows why?

Provide the layout or it is anybodies guess
